# Excel: Short notation numerical array

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to calculate a quadratic function (A, B & C) every line of the 200 previous entries. No problem using this formula:

=LINEST(ISNUMBER(Xpoints)*Ypoints;IF(Xpoints<>0;ISNUMBER(Ypoints)*Xpoints^{0\1\2};0);0)

- Select 3 horizontal cells ctrl+shift+enter.
- Some regional settings require {0,1,2} instead of {0\1\2}

I use this formula if there happens to be some empty cells in the dataset.
Xpoints have to go every line from 1 to 200.

My question is: I only can get this to work if i replace "Xpoints" with "{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,...,199,200}". Is there a short notation for this because it makes the formulas inconvenient and disordered. Ex. something like "{1:200}" But i tried that one already.

Thanks

Comment: Is your data in individual cells, such as D1:D200 or you are entering the numbers as a string?. If they are in cells then you can name a range ie my_x_data = D1:D200 , check out the insert menu and names...

Comment: I can perhaps make a table on some other sheet ranging from 1 to 200 and do a fixed reference. But I finaly found it. It is just "=ROW(1:200)"